# a4j:commandLink not work at first time

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I hava a rich:tabPanel where i can add and remove tab dynamically

```
<rich:tabPanel id="tabsPanel" switchType="client"  activeItem="#{tabsBean.activeTab}"   itemChangeListener="#{tabsBean.tabChange()}" >  
    <c:forEach var="tab" items="#{tabsBean.tabs}" >
            <rich:tab name="#{tab.name}" onheaderclick="switchTab('#{tab.name}');" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                         <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                             <h:outputText value="#{tab.name}" />
                                <h:graphicImage value="#{pathImmagini.pathImmagineElimina}" 
                                                style="width:12px; height:12px;" 
                                                onclick="myFunc('#{tab.name}'); Event.stop(event);"/>
                         </h:panelGrid>
                     </f:facet>
                    <h:form id="#{tab.name}" >
                                    <ui:include src="#{tab.pathComponent}" />
                            </h:form>
            </rich:tab>
    </c:forEach> 
 </rich:tabPanel>
```

where each tab has a its component *.xhtml (tab.pathComponent) , within of this components i have many a4j:commandlink that not works at first time.

this is one of my components (tab.pathComponent)

```
<rich:toolbar height="30" >
    <a4j:commandLink action="#{tab.setNewObject('Nuovo Cliente')}"                         render="pannelloDatiCliente" execute="@this"  >
        <h:graphicImage value="#{pathImmagini.pathImmagineAggiungiSoggetto}"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>                      
</rich:toolbar>
```

How i can do?

Comment: The bug with the second click was related to forms, where is your form defined ?

Comment: My form is defined as : <h:form> <ui:include src="pathOftheToolbar"> </h:form>

Comment: Also make sure you have no nested forms.

Comment: No , i don't have a nesterd form , this toolbar is located in a Tab within a TabPanel with switchType= client and also each tab is enclosed in a form

Comment: Do the first click send an ajax request ? If it, what contains the ajax request and the response ?

Answer (score 0):

can you give bit more information regarding your xhtml. normally second click problem happens because of partial rendereing of page or UI. Can't tell the problem only with this part of code.